# Why is the current through this ammeter 0A?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage

[image: Circuit]

I have the above circuit, and the current through the ammeter is 0A. But why is this the case? Is there any way I can easily show that the potential difference across that segment is 0V?

Also, the solution simply says that this is a balanced Wheatstone bridge, with that being the reason for I = 0. But why exactly is this the case? I can't really see any similarity between this and the balanced bridge except that the current through one segment is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you leave out the ammeter you've got two serial resistor pairs: 4 & 6 Ohm and 8 & 12 Ohm. Both work as voltage dividers in a 2:3 ratio.

Accordingly, the voltages in between each resistor pair are exactly the same. There's no difference in potential, so no current when connected.